# Generate random number without allocating new chunk of memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

`tf.random.uniform` does not have an `out` keyword.

Would tensorflow 2.0 allocate 2 x 2 arrays for 100 times in the following code?

If that is the case, how to avoid the unnecessary allocations on a GPU?

Thanks.

Test

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

for i in tf.range(tf.constant(100)):
    w = tf.random.uniform((2, 2), 0, 1, dtype=np.float32)
    # w is a tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor
    print(w)
```